# Тонкости настройки netbeans и git

Tags: git, netbeans

Эта замечательная IDE создаёт локальный репозиторий вместо того, что лежит на сервере.
В результате мои коммиты могут потереть изменения сделанные коллегой. Приходиться извращаться через консоль.
Можно ли как-то настроить это в netbeans?

P.s. эклипс не предлагать.

**UPD**
*По заявкам публики*
Клонируя проект, нетбинс создают локальную историю изменений, не связанную с историей изменений в центральном репозитории. В результате, если программист *через нетбинс* делает локально коммит своей ветки, сливает его с мастером и пуш на сервер, то нетбинс даже не стараеся подкачать последии изменения с сервера.

Набор комманд в моём случае примерно такой:

```
git add .  
git commit  
git checkout master  
git pull origin master:master  
git merge mybranche  
git push origin master:master
```

Comment: лолшто?

> та замечательная IDE создаёт локальный репозиторий вместо того, что лежит на сервере.
> В результате мои коммиты могут потереть изменения сделанные коллегой.

что-то я вообще не понимаю.

Ну и как вы извращаетесь в консоли?

Comment: пул - апдейт - коммит - пуш... это же гит, а не свн, у него должен быль локальный рэп

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте пустой проект. Далее меню *Группа*->*Git*->*Клонировать*.
Укажите нужные параметры (*URL/логин/пароль*).
Всё! Репозиторий заберется с сервера в папку проекта.
Управлять можно через *Группа->Git->Удаленный->(Выбрать/Вытянуть/Вытолкнуть)*